# Wrong Icons Theme, Sounds and Main Theme after Upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, icons, themes

I upgraded today my PC from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and get some visual issues. After upgrading I don't get the new Icons Theme, System Sounds and Main Theme from 20.04 LTS. It's the Adwaita Theme and Icons Theme. I had still Gnome Tweaks installed and tried to change it by hand to the new theme but I see any new. I got still all basic themes from 18.04 LTS. It's the same with the icons and system sounds. But the strange is it don't got any errors.

I Googled a bit but found not any usable solutions. I already tried `sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*`and `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache`but both without any effect. I don't know which log I have to show you but I hope `main.log` from `/var/log/dist-upgrade` is the right one. Here to the log: https://gist.github.com/Johnnii360/f9bb612cdce409afb59aa7c5a0acc574

Ah and btw. I also don't see any icons on desktop anymore.

Just a small info:

```
johannes@johannes:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
```

Here a list of all my installed packages: https://gist.github.com/Johnnii360/4b5fe2abb25e1d010b2eb9935b41af6f

I also run updates but nothing new. It's like there is also some missing - maybe. I upgraded the Notebooks from my Mother yesterday without any issues. Is there maybe some config file I have to show you?

[Ah and I always get this updates here but if I try to update it won't:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kbd1.png)

---

**Appendix:**
The icon from the Software Center (Ubuntu) is still the generic one. I also had installed the Gamemode but don't get the icon in the shell. And always get the updates in the Software Center. The Desktop Icons are also gone.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Solution for missing Yaru Theme including Icons and Sounds:

Manually installed it via apt/Synaptic Packet Manager.

#### 2. Solution for missing icons on Desktop:

Manually installed `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` via apt/Synaptic Packet Manager.

#### 3. Solution for Generic Software Center Icon:

I've seen it's just the GNOME Software Center. The Ubuntu Software Center (snap) has to be installed manually. I uninstalled the snap because GNOME Software is more all in all.